# possible to setup multi master with multi slave with galera with mariadb?

Tags: mariadb, database-replication, master-slave

recently, I learned how to use `galera` and setup master to master replication with mariadb but I am wondering if I can also use `galera` with some setting adjustment to have multi master and multi slave

let's say right now I have two master, I want I want to create two slave as back up in case of anything happened to both master.

I was reading this post
https://clanxii.altervista.org/blog/configure-mariadb-maxscale-master-slave-galera-cluster/ but it needs another server to do the proxy so I haven't give it a try yet if there is a better way

I thought of making all 4 master but then I realized if I do that, the `increment offset` would be totally off since the other two will never be used

Does anyone have an idea how this can be done?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Use 3 Masters, each in a different geographical location.  A flood, earthquake, tornado, etc, can't take out more than one.

If one dies, the other two continue running.  (With dual master, even a single failure requires manual intervention.)

But, since you are super paranoid, even if two are destroyed, the third is still there.  The only hassle is that it won't think it has a quorum.  (But with two masters and two slaves, you have worse hassles.)